# alphanumeric sorting in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am currently doing a project in which the database needs to sort the lot numbers

```
prefix is nvarchar
lotnum is int
suffix is nvarchar
```

I have managed to convert the lot number
code i used is

```
Select (case when prefix is null then '' else prefix end) +
CONVERT ( nvarchar , ( lotnumber ) ) +(case when suffix is null then '' else suffix end)
(values in the database are a1a,1a,1,2,100)
```

when I `order by lotnumber` I get

```
a1a
1a
1
2
100
```

then prefix to the order by
and get this result

```
1
a1a
1a
2
100
```

I have added the suffix as well and returns the same result

I need to order it as follows

```
1
1a
2
100
a1a
```

Please could someone help me on this

Comment: Are prefix,lotnum and suffix 3 columns in the table or a parts of a single columnn?

Comment: i think in your situation sorting should should be alphabetically.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Try to prepend and append space (' ') instead of empty string if prefix and suffix are not present, this way your sort by filed will be interpreted as varchar - you can still use a field without spaces for display.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried ordering by all three columns?

```
ORDER BY prefix, lotnum, suffix
```

By the way, I can see you're using SQL Server. To make things more portable, I'd recommend to use COALESCE and CAST instead of a CASE/WHEN and CONVERT for prefix and lotnum. Full query may look like this.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(prefix, '')
  + CAST(lotnum AS NVARCHAR)
  + COALESCE(suffix, '') AS lot_number
FROM
  YourTable
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(prefix, '')
  ,lotnum
  ,COALESCE(suffix, '')
```

Comment: I think the first suggestion was best.  I don't think he really wants to convert the lotnum to a string, so that 2 will sort before 100.  Rather than worrying about zero-filling or anything, just leave the data types alone and order by prefix, lotnum, suffix.

Comment: @GilM You're right, I left the CAST in the ORDER BY clause by mistake. Fixing it now.

Comment: I figured, @Diego.  By the way, I think leaving out the COALESCE functions in the ORDER BY will work fine, too.  Null values will sort to the top, I believe.